# ¿Cómo comparar un elemento de un array con el siguiente?

Tags: javascript, json

Hola que tal tengo una duda de como comparar un elemento de un array con los elementos siguientes y colocarle un numero consecutivo a los repetidos y a los que no un 1 por ejemplo:

Tengo un array que me trae estos datos:

```
"A001-001"
"A001-002"
"A001-003"
"A001-001"---> repetido
"A001-004"
"A001-005"
"A001-001"---> repetido
```

entonces tengo que ponerle un formato algo asi:

```
"A001-001" 1
"A001-002" 1
"A001-003" 1
"A001-001" 2
"A001-004" 1
"A001-005" 1
"A001-001" 3
```

lo e intententado de esta manera:

```
var cont = 0;
var cont2 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tmpData[cont] = {
      Numero: "",
      OE: 0
};
var elemento = {};
elemento[cont] = data[i].Numero.toString();
for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      if (elemento[cont] === data[j].Numero.toString()) {
          cont2++;
      } else {
          cont2 = 1;
      }
}            
tmpData[cont].Numero = data[i].Numero;            
tmpData[cont].OE = cont2;
cont++;
}
```

pero no logro conseguirlo, espero me puedan orientar, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El siguiente codigo te permite hacer lo que quieres:

```js
data = [
 "A001-001",
 "A001-002",
 "A001-003",
 "A001-001", // ---> repetido
 "A001-004",
 "A001-005",
 "A001-001", // ---> repetido
]
tmpData = {};
for (n in data) {
 if (!(data[n] in tmpData))
  tmpData[data[n]]=0;
 tmpData[data[n]]+=1;
}
console.log(tmpData)
```

Ahora si lo que quieres es mantener el **Arrays** sin cambios, solo añadiendo un valor de incremento:

```js
data = [
 "A001-001",
 "A001-002",
 "A001-003",
 "A001-001", // ---> repetido
 "A001-004",
 "A001-005",
 "A001-001", // ---> repetido
]
data2=[];
tmpData = {};
for (n in data) {
 if (!(data[n] in tmpData))
  tmpData[data[n]]=0;
 tmpData[data[n]]+=1;
 data2.push(data[n]+" "+tmpData[data[n]]);
}
console.log(data2);
```

Comment: Hola que tal, me parece bien el ejemplo pero este me cuenta las veces que esta repetido un elemento, lo que intento es que no me redusca el array que siga de la misma manera, solo que cuando alla uno repetido se incremento un contador, lo e conseguido de la siguiente manera;

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < dataOrdenado.length; i++) {
    tmpData[cont] = {
        NumeroControl: "",                
        OE: 0
     };
     var elemento = {};
     elemento[cont] = dataOrdenado[i].Numero.toString();
     for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
     if (elemento[cont] == dataOrdenado[j].Numero) {
         cont2++;
     } else {
          cont2 = 1;
     }
 }
 tmpData[cont].Numero = dataOrdenado[i].Numero;                 
 tmpData[cont].OE = cont2;                
cont++; } //lo siento pero aun no se identar aqui :P lo logro solo ordenando el array.

Comment: acabo de modificar la respuesta añadiendo un ejemplo donde muestro lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió demasiado, ademas de que me evitó lo molesto y lento del ordenamiento, saludos.

Comment: que bueno!. me alegro te haya servido, supongo que tu código hace el trabajo pero es evidente que estas sub-utilizando el lenguaje.. y recuerda.. califica la respuesta que mas se ajuste a tus requerimientos, Saludos!!;))..